# Using np.vectorize to create a column in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I have a data fram that contains two columns with numbers and a third column with repeating letters. Let's say somthing like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('xy'))
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] * int(len(df.index) / 4)
df['letters'] = letters
```

I want to create two new columns, which compares the number in columns 'x' and 'y' to the average of their corresponding letters. For example one new column will just contain the number 10 (if 20% or better than the mean), -10 (if 20% worse than the mean) or else 0.

I wrote the function below:

```
def scoreFunHigh(dataField, mean, diff, multip):

    upper = mean * (1 + diff)
    lower = mean * (1 - diff)

    if dataField > upper:
        return multip * 1
    elif dataField < lower:
        return multip * (-1)
    else:
        return 0
```

And then created the column as follows:

```
letterMeanX = df.groupby('letters')['x'].transform(np.nanmean)
df['letter x score'] = np.vectorize(scoreFunHigh)(df['x'], letterMeanX, 0.2, 10)

letterMeanY = df.groupby('letters')['y'].transform(np.nanmean)
df['letter y score'] = np.vectorize(scoreFunHigh)(df['y'], letterMeanY, 0.3, 5)
```

This works. However, I am getting the below runtime waring:

C:\Users\ ... \Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:2167: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in ? (vectorized)
  outputs = ufunc(*inputs)

(Please note, that if I am running the exact same code as above I am not getting the error. My real dataframe is much larger and I am using several functions for different data)

What is the problem here? Is there a better way to set this up?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why are you using `np.vectorize`?  It's tricky to use right, and never helps with speed.

Comment: @hpaulj even *more* tricky with `pandas` for essentially no benefit

Comment: @yank what exactly do you expect? Can you post a sample dataframe with just 10 rows and two letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is version that doesn't use `np.vectorize`

```
def scoreFunHigh(val, mean, diff, multip):

    upper = mean * (1 + diff)
    lower = mean * (1 - diff)

    if val > upper:
        return multip * 1
    elif val < lower:
        return multip * (-1)
    else:
        return 0

letterMeanX = df.groupby('letters')['x'].apply(lambda x: np.nanmean(x))
df['letter x score'] =  df.apply(
    lambda row: scoreFunHigh(row['x'], letterMeanX[row['letters']], 0.2, 10), axis=1)
```

Output

```
     x   y letters  letter x score
0   52  76       A               0
1   90  99       B              10
2   87  43       C              10
3   44  73       D               0
4   49   3       A               0
..  ..  ..     ...             ...
95  16  51       D             -10
96  38   3       A               0
97  43  47       B               0
98  58  39       C               0
99  41  26       D               0
```

Comment: I wouldn't describe `apply` as 'vectorized', but then `np.vectorized` isn't that either.  Both essentially iterate.  But `apply` is native to `pandas` and relatively easy to use.  'vectorize' in the 'true' numpy sense means doing the work with compiled numpy methods, which can't be done with your own row-wise python function.

Comment: Thank you both for the help. One follow-up question: `letterMeanX = df.groupby('letters')['x'].apply(lambda x: np.nanmean(x))` is repeated in a slightly different version throughout my code, for instance for the 'y score' as  `letterMeanY = df.groupby('letters')['y'].apply(lambda x: np.nanmean(x))`. This is very repetitive. Could it be simplified? Thanks again

Comment: @hpaulj you're right, I have edited my answer thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The sample you give does not produce the runtimewarning, so we can't do anything to help you diagnose it.  I don't know if a fuller traceback provides any useful information.

But lets look at the calculations:

```
In [70]: np.vectorize(scoreFunHigh)(df['x'], letterMeanX, 0.2, 10)              
Out[70]: 
array([-10,   0,  10, -10,   0,   0, -10, -10,  10,   0,   0,  10, -10,
       -10,   0,  10,  10, -10,   0,  10, -10, -10, -10,  10,  10, -10,
       ...
       -10,  10, -10,   0,   0,  10,  10,   0,  10])
```

and with the df assignment:

```
In [74]: df['letter x score'] = np.vectorize(scoreFunHigh)(df['x'], letterMeanX,
    ...:  0.2, 10) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [75]: df                                                                     
Out[75]: 
     x   y letters  letter x score
0   33  98       A             -10
1   38  49       B               0
2   78  46       C              10
3   31  46       D             -10
4   41  74       A               0
..  ..  ..     ...             ...
95  51   4       D               0
96  70   4       A              10
97  74  74       B              10
98  54  70       C               0
99  87  44       D              10
```

Often `np.vectorize` gives problems because of the `otypes` issue (read the docs);  if the trial calculation produces an integer, then the return dtype is set to that, giving problems if other values are floats.  However in this case the result can only have one of three values, [-10,0,10] (the last parameter).

The warning, such as you provide, suggests that some value(s) in the larger dataframe are wrong for the calculations in your `scoreFunHigh` function.  But the warning doesn't give enough detail to say what.

It is relatively easy to apply real numpy vectorization to this problem, since it depends on two Series, `df['x]` an `letterMeanX` and 2 scalars.

```
In [111]: letterMeanX = df.groupby('letters')['x'].transform(np.nanmean)        
In [112]: letterMeanX.shape                                                     
Out[112]: (100,)
In [113]: df['x'].shape                                                         
Out[113]: (100,)
In [114]: upper = letterMeanX *(1+0.2)                                          
In [115]: lower = letterMeanX *(1-0.2)                                          
In [116]: res = np.zeros(letterMeanX.shape,int)                                 
In [117]: res[df['x']>upper] = 10                                               
In [118]: res[df['x']<lower] = -10                                              
In [119]: np.allclose(res, Out[70])                                             
Out[119]: True
```

In other words, rather than applying the upper/lower comparison row by row, it applies it to the whole Series.  It is still iterating, but in compiled numpy methods, which are much faster.  `np.vectorize` is just a wrapper around an iteration.  It still calls your python function once for each row.  Hopefully the performance disclaimer is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. However, I ended up using apply. It is just easier for me to use and understand

Answer (score 2):

Consider directly calling your function with slight adjustment to method to handle conditional logic using [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) (or [**`numpy.where`**](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)). With this approach no loops are run but vectorized operations on the Series and scalar parameters:

```
def scoreFunHigh(dataField, mean, diff, multip): 

   conds = [dataField > mean * (1 + diff),
            dataField < mean * (1 - diff)]

   vals = [multip * 1, multip * (-1)]

   return np.select(conds, vals, default=0)


letterMeanX = df.groupby('letters')['x'].transform(np.nanmean) 
df['letter x score'] = scoreFunHigh(df['x'], letterMeanX, 0.2, 10) 

letterMeanY = df.groupby('letters')['y'].transform(np.nanmean) 
df['letter y score'] = scoreFunHigh(df['y'], letterMeanY, 0.3, 5)
```